# Creating a bus route

Tags: language-agnostic, graph-algorithm

What is a good algorithm, or class of algorithms that can be used to create a bus route?

I was thinking something along the lines of algorithms that are used to solve the Traveling Salesman, or Hamiltonian path problems, but in truth, neither really addresses the issue of how to move between two stops.

I would like the algorithm to have at least the following characteristics:

- produces a relatively optimized path (I understand that the problem is probably NP complete, so a good heuristic is fine)
- Can deal with parts of the path having different weights (eg time to travel over that part of the path)
- Can be forced to use a given starting and ending point (I don't think this one will be such a problem)

Code that can do this, or something like this would be appreciated (especially in C#), but a good algorithm by itself would be fine.

**Note:** While there are many algorithms that can find the shortest path between two points, I do not know the order in which I wish to stop. As such, unless I should be using a combination of two algorithms (which I doubt is the case), those algorithms do not do what I want (if you think that they do, please explain).

**Edit:** Assume I know all of the stops that need to be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a way to do this involves using the Floyd-Warshall algorithm, and then using an algorithm that is used to solve the traveling salesman problem.

This solves the problem of all the "optional" vertices (the intersections) and the uses the traveling salesman algorithm to determine the order in which the stops should be hit.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use the travelling salesman algorithm with a small modification/assumption here, to address point #2 (part of path having different weights).

Lets say Path from point "A" to Point "B" has 2 weights (say, traffic at some point of time)

Even though its a single path, we can simplify the problem by assuming a "virtual vertex", point "C" that is between "A" and "B", which will have fixed weights in each of the edges.

A-------Weight=10------ C ------Weight=15------B

On this new graph, run the Travelling salesman algorithm.

Comment: I think you understand. The issue that makes this problem different from the traveling salesman (as I understand it anyway, please correct me if I am mistaken) is that there are many vertexes that I do not need hit (i.e. every unused intersection). Is there a traveling salesman algorithm that can do this?

Comment: Well, if you absolutely do not need a vertex hit, then, you can increase the weight of all the edges leading to that vertex to "infinity", and the salesman problem mechanics will "naturally" avoid those edges. Your thoughts?

Comment: All of the intersections on the graph should be virtual vertices. They should be optionally hit, not never hit, or always hit.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Djikstra's algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstras_algorithm

The cost of travelling along an edge is not just the distance, but also related to the time until the "next" bus departs from the given node.  Note: you might already be on the bus when it stops at a node.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I do not want to catch a bus, I want to create the bus route. Not sure how Djisksra's can work in this situation...

Comment: I still don't understand, and I still think Dijkstra's algorithm applies, as it tells you the stops to make.  All roads lead to Rome, Dijkstra's algorithm tells you the best.  While Wikipedia refers to shortest path, the algorithm actually applies to lowest cost.  So apply costs relevant to your criteria.  If you wan to know how many people live within each node, add that as your criteria, and that should tell you the optimal path from A to B, so that you can pick up the most people.

Answer (score 1):

Bus routes are created by people, not computers. Only people know who needs to travel where and how often. You need at least such data to think about finding the set of routes that will be optimal to people's needs. In respect to that I think your question is underdefined.

Comment: See edit for clarification, but I think you are incorrect. I do not want a program to tell me where the stops should be, but in what order, and by what path the bus should stop at every stop. This seems like a very well defined question to me...

Comment: The point is you need to *define the constraints* - and there are **dozens** of them - and then just apply Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm is fine for the shortest path between two points. For this problem (as I see it anyway, please correct if I am mistaken) I first need to determine the order in which the points should be hit. Dijkstra's does not do this.

Comment: I think Ondrej's point is that it is easier to have a human know that the thousand people who work at the local Mill all live in Poortown and the two hundred people who work and shop in the local Mall all live in Richtown, your bus routes should reflect this knowledge -- that might mean your two bus lines _cross_ and never have any stops in common. Or they might run along the same two stops in opposite directions to make transfers easy. Or maybe they should both run a dozen stops in common and only split towards Richtown and Poortown and the Mill and the Mall.

Comment: @sarnold Yes, exactly. It's necessary to know the constraints and metrics imposed by passengers. They can be translated into edge metrics in a graph.